# How get coordinates of widget in qgrid layout in Qt

Tags: qt, qpushbutton, qgridlayout

I am trying to design a sudoku game with a grid layout full of qpushbuttons, At the momment of inserting a number in of the qpush button whihch is triggered when clicking on them I need to check if its a valid move depending on the other "cells". My problem is that i need the row and column of the qpushbutton that was clicked in qgridlayout but havent been able to find how to do it. Is there some way to obtain the coordinates of the qpushbutton clicked on the qgridlayout?

Answer (score 4):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/layout.html#horizontal-vertical-grid-and-form-layouts

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgridlayout.html#getItemPosition

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#indexOf

Your code should look something like:

```
int index = my_grid_layout->indexOf(clicked_widget);

if(index != -1)
{
    int row, col, col_span, row_span;
    my_grid_layout->getItemPosition(index, &row, &col, &col_span, &row_span);
    qDebug() << "Clicked Item is at:" << row << col 
             << "spanning" << row_span << col_span;
}
```

Hope that helps.